# CSS: Scrollbar for y-axis causes scrollbar for x-axis

Tags: css

Here's a [screenshot](http://www.laranevans.com/BadScrollbar.png) of the problem.

[image]

Basically, when the scrollbar shows up for the y-axis, the width of the container doesn't expand. Instead it just creates a scrollbar for the x-axis.

How can I get the container to expand without creating the x-axis scrollbar?

Comment: can you give an example of your css

Comment: whenever a vertical scrollbar appears, the content gets pushed to the left by the width of the scrollbar, so if your content is too narrow, this might cause the horizontal scrollbar to appear as well

Comment: can you please show your full code

Answer (score 23):

you can give this a try for the element:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

you can use `scroll` or `auto` for the `overflow-y`

here is a page with some samples: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: I think `overflow-x: hidden;` will hide the data as well, which might not be expected.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem at all. Instead, the content is cutoff with no ability to scroll left/right to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I am using material-ui . It works as the *flexbox*, I had set the direction attribute as column. Because of which my **extra content was overflowing to right side instead of overflowing to the bottom**. That's why *overflow-x* and *overflow-y* weren't working as expected. I removed the `direction="column"` attribute and then I got the desired behavior from *overflow-x* and *overflow-y*.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a solution as well.

```
overflow-x: visible; 
overflow-y: scroll;
```

The above code doesn't work since the pairing of visible with either scroll or auto sets the visible property to auto.
You can read more about it here: https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Looks like there's no CSS way to get what you want as far as I can tell. if someone finds another workaround, I'd be grateful to know!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Once you earn some reputation you could comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue close to this.

I was able to style my scrollbar using

```
div {

  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;

       &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 12px;
      }
    
      &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #63377e;
        border-radius: 12px;
      }

}
```

[first try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syLH5.png)

You will notice that the scroll thumb on the x-axis is different from that of the y-axis, although if I use `overflow-x: hidden;` that will remove the scrollbar on the x-axis, it will also make the div not scroll on the x-axis (I need it to scroll).
The fix is adding `height` to `::-webkit-scrollbar`, apparent width works for the y-axis and height works for the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have padding around the scrolling area anyway, a more recent CSS solution is to set the property `scrollbar-gutters: stable both-edges;`. This will always include space for the vertical scrollbar, but only draws the scrollbar when needed. You can remove the `both-edges` part to just have padding on one edge.

It is not ideal, but at least a little better than setting `overflow-y: scroll;` or `overflow-x: hidden;`. I use it in my popup component. In most cases my popups don't need scroll, but I can set this once on my popup component and know the few scrolling cases will look good enough.

MDN docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter

That page points out it is currently not supported on Safari.